# What is Hang Input in Logic Design?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, output, input

When it comes in Digital Logic Design using IC (Integrated-Circuit) what is the term **HANG Input** means? what does it do? and how will it affect the output of the IC?

Comment: I've never met the term before. Link to where you saw this, the context might give some clues.

Comment: http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~strandh/Teaching/AMP/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/gates.html let me quote the line where I saw it "A gate that ignores both its inputs and always gives 0 on the output. This gate does not require any circuits. Just let the inputs hang and connect the output to a 0."

Comment: looks like what they meant is to keep the inputs disconnected..aka..floating

Comment: Am i reading the right thing about Hang Input? Link: https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-floating-input-gate

Comment: So a "hang input" is just an input that is left open, or floating?  Never heard it described that way before.  In the referenced article, I guess I would have used the phrase "just leave the inputs open" or "let them float".

Comment: It would be valuable to reference the info page in your question text so it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article you link to, in all cases, the 'hang input' is taken to a static input level so that it doesn't participate in the logic switching of the gate. For example, to make an inverter out of a 2 input NAND gate, one input is used for the logic, the other is held static high to enable the other one to work.